# Django rest framework - PrimaryKeyRelatedField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am following the Django REST framework tutorial, and I am at this point  here: 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions#adding-endpoints-for-our-user-models

My code for UserSerializer looks like:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

I am trying to understand what is PrimaryKeyRelatedField exactly. To do so I am doing changing the code as follows and refreshing the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/` to see different outputs

**Variation 1**

```
snippets = serializers.RelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)


{
    "count": 1, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "username": "som", 
            "snippets": [
                "Snippet title = hello", 
                "Snippet title = New2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is printing out the `__unicode__()` value of the snippets. I expected this

**Variation 2** - using PrimaryKeyRelatedField

```
snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)


{
    "count": 1, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "username": "som", 
            "snippets": [
                1, 
                2
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This prints out the primary key id of the two snippets - **I don't understand this**

**Variation 3 - commenting out also produces**

```
#snippets = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

{
    "count": 1, 
    "next": null, 
    "previous": null, 
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1, 
            "username": "som", 
            "snippets": [
                1, 
                2
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [Serializer Docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers)

> The default ModelSerializer uses primary keys for relationships

If you don't specify anything yourself `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` will be used under the hood, so your Variation 2 is the expected output.

Hopefully that helps.